# Search if a string exists in a list

Tags: c#

```
    public bool VerifyId(List<string> sheetData)
    {
        if (sheetData.Where(q => q == "-1007401").First())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I have this bool function where if it finds that string, it returns true. But why is the **Where** not working?

Comment: Your code does not compile

Comment: [IEnumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0)

Comment: But i would like that if it finds the first, it automatically returns true. I cant do that with Contains.

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation @hikitan1? That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. You are completely right! Thank you

Comment: Is it [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)? Shouldn't it be tagged as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using the *list.Contains(string)* function.

```
if (sheetData.Contains("-1007401")
  return true
else
  return false
```

Comment: You could just `return sheetData.Contains("-1007401");`. This would yield the same result